# Cambiar un decimal a binario con stack java

Tags: java, stack

Buen dia, estoy intentando hacer un convertidor de decimales a binario, octal y hexadecimal y vise versa, pero la no me muestra los valores correctos ni eh podido pasar de binario a decimal, alguna idea?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack pila = new Stack();
    int op;
    long n1 = 0;

    System.out.println("Menu de Opciones:");
    System.out.println("1. Convertir un numero decimal a binario.");
    System.out.println("2. Convertir un numero binario a decimal.");
    System.out.println("3. Convertir un numero decimal a octal.");
    System.out.println("4. Convertir un numero octal a decimal.");
    System.out.println("5. Convertir un numero decimal a hexadecimal.");
    System.out.println("6. Convertir un numero hexadecimal a decimal.");
    System.out.println("7. Salir.");
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print("Ingrese la Opcion que requiere: ");
    op = keyb.nextInt();

    switch (op) {

        case 1:
            System.out.print("Ingrese el numero decimal: ");
            n1 = keyb.nextInt();
            long aux = n1;
            long binario;
            while (aux >=0){
                binario = aux%2;
                pila.push(binario);
                aux /= 2;
            }
            while (pila.empty() == false) {
                System.out.print(pila.pop());
            }
            break;
        case 2:

            break;

        case 3:

            break;

        case 4:

            break;
        case 5:

            break;

        case 6:

            break;

        case 7:
            System.out.print("Programa terminado.");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.print("ERROR! /N"
                    + "Opcion incorrecta, intente de nuevo.");

    }

}
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

Saludos, Carlos.

Respondiendo únicamente a tu pregunta sobre la conversión de decimal a binario, el problema que tienes es bastante simple:

```
while (aux >=0) {
    binario = aux%2;
    pila.push(binario);
    aux /= 2;
}
```

Tu programa no pasa de este `while`, porque el valor de `aux` nunca será un número negativo, al momento de realizar la división, el último valor es el 0, simplemente deberías cambiar el operador lógico `>=` por `>`, de esta manera, cuando el `aux` tome el valor de 0, terminará el bucle y continuará tu programa, quedando de esta manera:

```
while (aux > 0) {
    binario = aux%2;
    pila.push(binario);
    aux /= 2;
}
```

Hice una prueba intentando convertir el decimal 50 a binario y aquí está el resultado.

[image: img]

La comprobación la obtuve de esta [calculadora binaria en línea](https://es.calcuworld.com/calculadoras-matematicas/calculadora-binaria/)

[image: img2]

Comment: Respondí únicamente a esta pregunta, porque a mi parecer, es el único problema que tienes, no sé si también tienes problemas con los demás sistemas, ya que no los agregaste

Comment: Hola Rodriguez, gracias por tu respuesta, pero mi problema es literalmente la pila (stack) con el metodo no me imprime.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que tienes con la pila?

Comment: uuff, me acaba de correr jajaja solo tenia q cambiarlo a string para cuardarlo en la pila... que pna molestarte jajajajja mil gracias!
ahora solo falta q imprima al contraro el binario jajajaja

Comment: ¡Qué bueno que te funcionó!